# For loop inside a class object in Python

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I'm creating a class in Python and passing a list (simbolList) through a for loop (generating data from those stocks), however, I don't seem to figure out the logic behind this just yet. Any suggestions?

In essence, I want to pass the symbolList through the for loop and for each symbol passed, retrieve the stock data and save it in a dictionary (data dict), but it doesn't seem to be working

This is the code

```
class Stocks:
    symbolList = ["AMZN"]
    data = {}

    def __init__(self, symbolList):
        self.symbolList = symbolList
        self.data = data

    def symbol(self):
        for symbol in self.symbolList:
            self.data[symbol] = get_data(symbol)
        print(self.data)
Stocks.symbol() #yields an errors, missing 1 required positional argument self
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are looking for. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Did you just forget the `self.` in front of `symbolList` and `data`? It should be `self.symbolList` and `self.data`.

Comment: I bascially want to pass the symbolList through the for loop in the function "symbol". The "get_data" will retrieve stock data for each symbol in the SymbolList and I want to save that retrieved data in a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using both class and instance attributes; you probably don't want to be doing that.  Here's the code using only instance attributes:

```
class Stocks:
    def __init__(self, symbolList):
        self.symbolList = symbolList
        self.data = {}

    def symbol(self):
        for symbol in self.symbolList:
            self.data[symbol] = get_data(symbol)
        print(self.data)

stocks = Stocks(["AMZN"])
stocks.symbol()
```

Note that the "missing `self`" error is because you're trying to call an *instance method* on a *class*.  The above code fixes this by creating an instance called `stocks`, which is what provides the `self` parameter when you call the `symbol()` method.

FWIW since the `symbol` method is actually loading data from an external source, for *all* the symbols, I might suggest naming it differently; you can also write it a bit more concisely with a dictionary comprehension.

```
class Stocks:
    def __init__(self, symbolList):
        self.symbolList = symbolList
        self.data = {}

    def load_symbol_data(self):
        self.data = {symbol: get_data(symbol) for symbol in self.symbolList}


stocks = Stocks(["AMZN"])
stocks.load_symbol_data()
print(stocks.data)
```